# Adding features from GeoJSON in hidden form field in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, forms

I have an HTML form that includes some maps where the user can add features. The data is being saved in a hidden form field as GeoJSON. Example (simplified id and name attributes):

```
<input type="hidden" name="field-name" id="field-id" value="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;FeatureCollection&quot;,&quot;features&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Feature&quot;,&quot;geometry&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;LineString&quot;,&quot;coordinates&quot;:[[0.00011777958861592853,0.00046299946119177093],[0.00011808029039121804,0.000462849815107802],[0.00011774720534782042,0.0004628315852670539],[0.00011778575685747292,0.00046289010985844925],[0.00011771173795894013,0.00046290929640235845]]},&quot;properties&quot;:{}},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Feature&quot;,&quot;geometry&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;LineString&quot;,&quot;coordinates&quot;:[[13.109962200927734,51.540330426226575],[13.117858624267575,51.53178825435282],[13.109447216796871,51.52954566858696]]},&quot;properties&quot;:{}}]}">
```

When the user reloads the page without submitting the form, the hidden field value is still present and I want to newly add the features to the map. How do I do this? My approach so far was:

```
if(document.getElementById('field-id').value) {
  format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
  source[id].addFeatures(format.readFeatures(document.getElementById('field-id').value));
}
```

where `source` is the `ol.layer.source.Vector` that has breviously been set. Unfortunately, the features are not being added. Is this the correct approach in general? If so, where's the error?

Comment: You are using double quote `"` within an HTML string which is delimited by double quote.  Change either the inner or outer ones to single quote (works with Chrome) or for strict browser compatibility replace the inner ones with `&quot;`.  Also unless your view uses EPSG:4326 you will need to specify the projection as the `featureProjection` option for `readFeatures`.

Comment: Sorry, stupid copy & paste error, it has `&quot;` in the original output, as edited now. And thanks Mike, yes, it's the projection issue. That's why I had no error message and still saw nothing.